# Can Xamarin Studio export Native LIbarys

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, xamarin, native

I would like to create a library for my webservice so people can easily use my service in their native app. My Targets are WP8, iOS, and Android.

I was wondering can I export a C# code base to a .jar / .a / dll for each respected platform for my client library as I would much prefer maintaining 1 code base vs 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a .NET DLL that can be used in WP8, or any .NET platform.  You cannot create libraries for native Android/iOS use.